# Using maps and sets together as a data structure in Java

Tags: java, set, maps

i have a program that takes tracks and how many times it was played and output it.. simple.. but i couldn't make the counting in a descending order. My second problem is that if there are multiple tracks with the same count, it should look at the track's name and print them in alphabetical order.. i reached the point where i can print everything as it should be without the order though, because I am using maps and whenever I use a list to sort it out, it gets sorted in ascending order.

**Here is my code and output**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;
import lab.itunes.*;

public class Music     {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception     {
    try  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out);
    Map<String,Integer> mapp = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    output.print("Enter the name of the iTunes library XML file:");
    String entry = input.nextLine();
    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(entry));
    Library music = new Library(entry); // this class was given to us.
    Iterator<Track> itr = music.iterator(); // scan through it
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        Track token = itr.next(); // get the tracks
        mapp.put(token.getName(),token.getPlayCount()); // fill our map 
         list1.add(token.getPlayCount()); // fill our list too 
    }
    for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> testo : mapp.entrySet())  {
        String keys = testo.getKey(); 
        Integer values = testo.getValue();
        output.printf("%d\t%s%n",values,keys); // printing the keys and values in random order.
    }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException E)   {
        System.out.print("That file does not exist");
    }
}
```

}

the output is this..

```
Enter the name of the iTunes library XML file:library.txt
87  Hotel California
54  Like a Rolling Stone
19  Billie Jean
75  Respect
26  Imagine
19  In the Ghetto
74  Macarena
27  Hey Jude
67  I Gotta Feeling
99  The Twist
```

can you please give me a hint for this? i worked for at least 4 hours to get this far.. thanks

Comment: Was not using TreeMap with a custom Comparator a conscious decision? If not, that's a good place to start.

Comment: Hashmap docs: "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map" see - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: However, you can use Collections.sort() on your List<String> to sort alphabetically, then iterate through the list (which are the keys to your hashmap) and retrieve the integer for each string.

Comment: You could also create a class - I'll call it `Track` - implementing `Comparable<T>` with two fields: `Name` and `PlayCount`. Implement the interface methods (including `equals` and `hashCode`), then make a `List<Track>` and use `Collections.sort()`.  Your `compareTo` would be able to sort by play count and break ties alphabetically just like you want it to.

Comment: @adamdc78 I tried useing a treeMap but i get the same results, not sure what do u mean by comparator tho... but thanks :)

Comment: A [Comparator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Futil%2FComparator.html&ei=cDywVOaYOMbcoASD64LIDg&usg=AFQjCNHEdTSnUSU9eNxLWGqdpPwdfT75Ug&sig2=boXq0ZO4b97R4pSVuDG83g&bvm=bv.83339334,d.cGU&cad=rja) provides the logic for the comparison of two objects.  Using the custom class with `Comparable<T>` is probably the better approach; much more maintainable and if the sort logic ever gets more complex (including more fields for instance) it's very maintainable.

Comment: @Brian when i use the list

Comment: @Ayman, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `Library` class have a `sort()` method? If not, you could add one and call sort() on the Library `music` just before you ask it for its `iterator()`.

```
public class Library
{
    // ... existing code ...

    public void sort()
    {
        class TrackPlayCountComparator implements Comparator<Track>
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Track t1, Track t2) {
                int compare = t2.getPlayCount() - t1.getPlayCount();
                if (compare == 0) {
                    return t1.getName().compareTo(t2.getName());
                }
                return compare;
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(this.tracks, new TrackPlayCountComparator());
    }
}
```

Simplifies your code to this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the name of the iTunes library XML file: ");
        String entry = input.nextLine();
        try {
            input = new Scanner(new File(entry));
            input.close();
            Library music = new Library(entry); // this class was given to us.
            music.sort(); // sort the tracks
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(System.out)
            for (Iterator<Track> itr = music.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
                Track track = itr.next();
                output.printf("%d\t%s%n", track.getPlayCount(), track.getName());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException E) {
            System.out.print("That file does not exist");
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks bro but this method is kinda advanced for me and i am not allowed to add any methods to the class library.. there must be a simpler way.. thanks alot doe!

Comment: Adding a comparator is the correct answer; if you cannot add new methods, view my answer below to see how to add your comparator as an anonymous class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is: how can I sort a map on the values, rather than the keys?

If so, here is some sample code to get you started:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "\t + entry.getValue())
    .forEach(output::println);
```

If you need to sort in reverse order then just change the comparingByValue comparator:

```
.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue((val1, val2) -> val2 - val2))
```

To sort by value then alphabetically:

```
.sorted((entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() == entry2.getValue() ? entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey())) : entry2.getValue() - entry1.getValue())
```

You could make that a bit neater by putting the comparator in a separate method.

```
private Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> songComparator() {
    return (entry1, entry2) -> {
        int difference = entry2.getValue() - entry1.getValue();
        if (difference == 0) {
            return entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey()));
        } else {
            return difference;
        }
    }
}
```

you would then use `songComparator` to generate the comparator for `sorted`.

Comment: thanks bro, but i can't add methods to the class yet.. if there is another way i can use comparator to sort my tracks play count ?...

Comment: Yes you can create your own Comparator (either a separate class or an anonymous class).

Answer (score 0):

Use Collections.sort() to sort a collection by its [natural order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html), or define a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and pass it as the second argument.

First you must change your List to take the 'Track' type, and you no longer need a Map:

```
// the list will store every track
List<Track> tracks = new ArrayList<Track>();

String entry = input.nextLine();
Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(entry));
Library music = new Library(entry); // this class was given to us.
Iterator<Track> itr = music.iterator(); // scan through it
while (itr.hasNext()) {
    tracks.add(itr.next()); // add each track
}

// you can define classes anonymously:
Collections.sort(tracks, new Comparator<Track>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Track t1, Track t2) {
        int diff = t2.getPlayCount() - t1.getPlayCount();
        // if there is no difference in play count, return name comparison
        return (diff == 0 ? t1.getName().compareTo(t2.getName()) : diff);
    }
});
```

See [Anonymous Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) for more information.